# tengo 4 listas y hay que convertirlas de formato ancho a formato largo utilizando como variable de organización los años utilizando un ciclo para

Tags: r

```
library(reshape2)

#crear las 4 listas
lista <- rep(list(NA),4)
for (i in 1:4){
  lista[[i]]<- read_excel(path="API_NV.AGR.TOTL.ZS_DS2_es_excel_v2_45415.xls", sheet=i)
}
#convertirlas de ancho a largo
for (i in 1:4){
  lista.melt[[i]]<-melt(lista[[i]])
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**y el archivo contiene esta información, en donde en la fila 1 se encuentran los años y en la columna 1 los paises, el objetivo de este proceso es tener tanto paises como años en columnas**

Comment: Bienvenido nico rozo a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Para darte una respuesta apropiada, en primer lugar deberíamos conocer como quedan las estructuras de los data.frames leídos, particularmente para saber los nombres de columnas. ¿Podrías agregar la salida de `str(lista[[1]]` a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que es lo que estas buscando

```
library(reshape2)

lista <- rep(list(NA),4)
lista.melt <- rep(list(NA),4)

for(i in 1:4){
lista[[i]] <- data.frame(`Country Name` = c("Aruba","Afganistán","Angola","Albania","Andorra",
                    "El mundo árabe","Emiratos Árabes Unidos","Argentina","Armenia","Samoa Americana"),
                    `1960` = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 35),
                    `1961` = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 35),
                    `1962` = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 35),
                    `1963` = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 35),
                    `1964` = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 35),
                    `1965` = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 35),
                    `1966` = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 35),
                    `1967` = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 35),
                    `1968` = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 35),
                    `1969` = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 35),
                    `1970` = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 45, sd = 35),
                    check.names = F)
}


for(i in 1:4) lista.melt[[i]] <- melt(data = lista[[i]], id = "Country Name")
lista.melt
```